# Firebase remote config : create role "Viewer" and" Editor Remote Config"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-iam, firebase-remote-config

Is it possible to create a permission role between "Viewer" and "Editor" :

- I want to get all the same permission of the "Viewer" + being able to update remote config ONLY.

If yes, how to do please ?

Comment: please post the solution as an answer separately not in the question it self and then accept that answer as solution , so that system can understand that the question is answered and it will be easy for others to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin

IAM & Admin > IAM > "+ Grand Access" and adding email in principals and adding two roles "Firebase Viewer" and "Firebase Remote Config Admin"

[image]